# SQL: Update values in column based on another

Tags: sql

I have an SQL table, 1 column has stuff written in this way 'AAAA-BB-CC', and the second one has values written in the following format 'XXXX YYYYYY'

How can I make a SQL query that would make the 2nd column 'AAAA-BB-CC YYYYYY'. Basically I want to take the value in column 1 + the 2nd part of the value in column 2 and update column 2 to have this new value

Comment: Consider creating a view instead. To avoid data inconsistency.

Comment: This sounds like a use-case for a computed / generated column. Exactly how depends on your specific RDBMS which you have not indicated.